# Pokemon Egg Disappearing

Tags: pokemon-go

So my Pokemon eggs are reaching "maturity" then they just disappear. I don't get a new Pokemon. The egg just disappears. I had this happen with a 2k and a 5k now. Is this happening to anyone else?

Comment: This happened to me the other day, try sorting your Pokemon by recent and see if there's anything at the top that you don't remember catching.

Comment: [Related](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278539/lost-my-10km-egg-and-dont-know-why)

Comment: this is what happens when they are more worried about bots and tools (pokevision) then making an actual working game.

Answer (score 4):

It does seem that this is a common problem (there [are](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4toaom/does_the_journal_not_show_what_hatched_from_the/) [multiple](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4sd25q/missing_pokemon_after_egg_hatch/) Reddit threads about it). It is possible that it hatched but you didn't see the notification for some reason. Sort your Pokemon by recent and then compare that against your journal; Pokemon hatched from eggs don't appear there, so if there is a recent Pokemon that is not in your journal, it is likely from the egg. It is also possible that the egg is simply gone, though. Unfortunately, like most issues, this is likely related to server instability. You may want to save your 10 km eggs until the game is more stable.

Comment: Cross-referencing the journal and recent Pokemon list seems like a good advice. It saved me a lot of headache just today. It also shouldn't be too hard, if you catch it early.

Comment: It works for lots of things. Spun a stop and it didn't seem like it worked? Tried to catch something and the game froze? Check your journal. Chances are it actually did give it to you. It saves me a lot of frustration